# How to create an Order using Square Connect API?

Tags: square-connect

I tried the following request to create an order using Square Connect's Orders API (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-orders). The response I got back was "not found". I wonder if I am missing anything in my request?

Request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -H "Accept: application/json" \
         -H "Authorization: Bearer repace-with-real-access-token" \
         -d '{}' \
         https://connect.squareup.com/v1/locationId/orders
```

Response:

```
{"type":"not_found","message":"NotFound"}
```

If this is not the correct way to create an order, can you please let me know how to do it using Square Connect API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-d '{}'`. The endpoint takes GET requests and by default, this argument will make curl send POST instead of GET requests.

Comment: POST is what I actually wanted to do, but Connect V1 does not seem support that. I tried that because the API doc says: "For POST and PUT endpoints, you provide request parameters as JSON in your request's body." I hope you guys could remove the word "POST" from that sentence.

Comment: I misunderstood your question earlier. If you wanted to do a PUT, then you intend to update an order (we don't have a POST endpoint for orders because we don't allow order creation). This means that you need to also specify the order ID as well. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#put-orderid